# Destructuring a function's return statement, but don't replace existing variables

Tags: javascript, function, variables, coffeescript, destructor

In CoffeeScript, I like to use destructuring assignments when returning functions with multiple return values. It makes it clearer what is being returned, versus returning an array.

For instance, returning an array from a function in JavaScript:

```
function getSumAndDiff(firstNumber, secondNumber) {
  var sum = firstNumber + secondNumber
  var difference = firstNumber - secondNumber

  return [sum, difference]
}

var values = getSumAndDiff(10, 5)
var sum = values[0]
var difference = values[1]
```

While in CoffeeScript, returning an object from a function:

```
getSumAndDiff = (firstNumber, secondNumber) ->
  sum = firstNumber + secondNumber
  difference = firstNumber - secondNumber

  {sum, difference}

{sum, difference} = getSumAndDiff(10, 5)
```

However, the problem is that the CoffeeScript method replaces any existing variables called `sum` and `difference`. So if I ran this function multiple times in succession, then they would keep overwriting the previous one.

There are several ways of resolving this, of course, such as simply by assigning the returned variables to other names each time, like so:

```
{sum, difference} = getSumAndDiff(10, 5)
sum1 = sum
difference1 = difference

{sum, difference} = getSumAndDiff(11, 6)
sum2 = sum
difference2 = difference
```

But is there a cleaner way of doing it? Or, is perhaps the best solution to simply return an array when I need to run a function like this multiple times in a row? Or would closures make sense, or is that too much excessive code? I'm just wondering if there's something I'm perhaps missing, because I figure there's got to be a cleaner way of doing this, especially with CoffeeScript? Or maybe my general approach to this is flawed, such as I should instead only have one return value per function instead, to simplify things?

Comment: What do you mean by "*replaces any existing variables*"? It's just the standard coffeescript scoping rules. [Your posted example](http://coffeescript.org/#try:getSumAndDiff%20%3D%20(firstNumber%2C%20secondNumber)%20-%3E%0A%20%20sum%20%3D%20firstNumber%20%2B%20secondNumber%0A%20%20difference%20%3D%20firstNumber%20-%20secondNumber%0A%0A%20%20%7Bsum%2C%20difference%7D%0A%0A%7Bsum%2C%20difference%7D%20%3D%20getSumAndDiff(10%2C%205)) works well.

Comment: It is not quite clear what you are asking for. Are you looking for some way to _accumulate_ values?

Comment: I am mostly looking for a better way of organizing my code, I suppose. Perhaps Programmers.SE would have been the better place to post this? Although I thought it would be too code-heavy for there. And when I say "replace existing variables", basically I mean when I already have an existing `sum` and `difference` vars that were previously set by calling the `getSumAndDiff` function, which I intend on calling multiple times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### What you have now...

Ok, I get the point now. When you write:

```
getSumAndDiff = (firstNumber, secondNumber) ->
  sum = firstNumber + secondNumber
  difference = firstNumber - secondNumber

  {sum, difference}
```

The function `getSumAndDifference` returns an *associative array* (well, an *object*) having for key the name of the variables and for value their content. This is only syntactic sugar equivalent to:

```
{ 'sum': sum, 'diff': diff }
```

That associative array is the value returned and you then use *object destructing* to get back the various fields of interest:

```
{sum, difference} = getSumAndDiff(10, 5)
```

Once again this is only syntactic sugar around:

```
_obj =  getSumAndDiff(10, 5)
sum = _obj['sum']
diff = _obj['diff']
```

### ... now, for some alternatives

**1) Aliased object destructuring**

First, as you explained yourself, you can use "aliased" object destructing to get back the values as an other name:

```
{sum:x, diff: y} = getSumAndDiff(10, 5)
```

This will set `x` to the same value as field `sum` of the returned object. And `y` as the same value as the field `diff`.

Syntactic sugar around:

```
_obj = getSumAndDiff(10, 5)
x = _obj['sum']
y = _obj['diff']
```

<sub>As a side note, notice again how `{sum,diff}` was in fact a shortcut to write `{sum: sum, diff: diff}`</sub>

**2) Array destructuring**

An other, somehow simpler alternative, is not to return an *object* but an *array* (more formally, a *numerically indexed array*) :

```
getSumAndDiff = (firstNumber, secondNumber) ->
  sum = firstNumber + secondNumber
  difference = firstNumber - secondNumber

  [sum, difference]  ## <-- array [ ... ] not object { ... }
```

With that syntax, `sum` and `diff` are returned as the item of index `0` and `1` resp. of an array. From caller side, you might then use *array destructuring* to extract those values:

```
[sum, diff] = getSumAndDiff(10, 5)
```

As the array is numerically indexed, you don't have to bother about field names. So you can write that too:

```
[x, y] = getSumAndDiff(10, 5)
[sum2, diff2] = getSumAndDiff(10, 5)
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so I figured it out. I know that my question wasn't the clearest. Really, I was looking for a way to simplify my code, rather than finding an exact solution to an exact problem.

I realize now that since CoffeeScript's destructuring assignments are really just objects being passed from the return value to the global scope, basically, then I can just "rename" the variables on the spot by passing it to a different variable. (Not the greatest explanation... see examples below.)

For instance, `return { test }` really just means `return { test: test }` (which I knew before, but eventually forgot that it meant that).

**So, rather than having `{sum, difference} = getSumAndDiff(10, 5)`, I can instead do `{sum: sum2, difference} = getSumAndDiff(10, 5)`.**

This results in `sum2` being set, rather than `sum`, which would replace `sum` if it has been set before, by calling the same function, for instance.

Just one of the quirks of using CoffeeScript, I guess! (Primarily the `{ test }` means `{ test: test }` notation.)